# dynamic alias in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I want query field with different alias in stored  procedure

```
select COUNT(EmpCode) as  CountEmp+@para
```

result shoud be

CountEmp1

### 45

CountEmp2

### 54

CountEmp1

### 76

Query loop in c# code:

```
select COUNT(EmpCode) where something = @something as CountEmp+@para
```

Comment: what problem you face? also add the code

Comment: you can't do dynamic alias (unless you use Dynamic SQL). What is the purpose of doing that ?

Comment: You want Pass different table name dynamically?

Comment: Whatever alias will be you cann't get different value just by renaming it. Please show all the query[s] text which produced these values.

Comment: i am fill query result in c# datatable by loop by matching primary key but if everytime column name same like [empcode] datatable override query result on every iteration , so  want to pass parameter by c# to change alias name differ column name

Comment: For this you have to use dynamic sql

Comment: Please edit your question to include your current attempt (including the iteration you talked about). Probably a different, set based approach will help you better.

Comment: query loop select COUNT(EmpCode)  where something = @something  as  CountEmp+@para

Comment: in 2nd iteration i want different result  with different alias like empcode1 , empcode2 so on....

Comment: @KashifFaraz I understood what you want; however I think you are going about this the wrong way. Perhaps if we understood the bigger picture, we could recommend a different approach, one that doesn't require dynamic sql.

Comment: how many different `empcodes` do you want to count? If there aren't too many you could get a count of them all in one call with each field having the alias you are after.

Comment: @KashifFaraz, you are using ad-hoc query already. What is stopping you from building column name depending on parameter value on client-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach without dynamic SQL:

```
--I create temp table for demonstration
DECLARE @some_table TABLE (
    Something int,
    EmpCode INT
)

INSERT INTO @some_table (Something, EmpCode)
VALUES (1, 10),(1, 22),(1, 12),(2, 12),(2, 30),(3, 65),(3, 15),(3, 11),(3, 5)

--Declare parameter we want to search
DECLARE @param int = 1

--Query
--In cte we select what we need based on parameter
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  'CountEmp'+CAST(@param as nvarchar(10)) as SomeThing,
        CAST(COUNT(EmpCode) as nvarchar(10)) as EmpCodeCount,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeThing ) as rn
FROM @some_table
WHERE SomeThing = @param
GROUP BY SomeThing
)
--And here comes UNION
SELECT SomeThing as Result
FROM (
    SELECT SomeThing,rn
    FROM cte
    UNION ALL
    SELECT EmpCodeCount ,rn
    FROM cte
    ) as t
ORDER BY rn, SomeThing DESC
```

Output:

```
Result
------------------
CountEmp1
3

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make use of below code. Its working fine with SQL Server 2012.

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('temp..#Mytable') IS NOT NULL
CREATE TABLE #Mytable (ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),EmpCode  INT)
DECLARE @max int ,@count int 
SET @max =0;
DECLARE @str varchar(10)
INSERT #Mytable
(EmpCode)
VALUES
(10),
(45),
(35),
(63),
(56),
(65)

SET @count = (SELECT COUNT (ID) FROM #Mytable )
WHILE @count > @max
BEGIN 
    SET @max = @max+1
    SET @str = CONVERT(varchar(10),@max)
    EXEC('SELECT EmpCode AS Empcode'+@str+ ' FROM #Mytable WHERE ID = '+@str)
END
```